# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined

Tags: asp.net, ajax

When I run my project on IE 9, I get the following error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'JSON' is undefined

I have tried online suggestions but none of them worked for me. If i run my project using Chrome then everything works fine.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Maybe there's an issue with your code. Would you like us to guess what your code looks like?

Comment: My psychic debugging skills tell me you're in compatibility mode.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with my code its after installing jquery 2.0.3 i get this error? @SLaks how do i change the compatibility mode?

Comment: Look in the address bar or the dev tools

Comment: under browser mode it says: IE9 and under document Mode it says: IE9 standards

Answer (score 3):

I think your website is running in Quirk Mode in IE9, try to set the proper html doctype, you can also try [Json3](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/) script.

Comment: I have added: <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.2.6/json3.min.js"></script> on my master page but i am getting the same error? do i have to download any files for this script to work?

Comment: No, make sure you are including the json script before jquery script.

Comment: It still not working i have included the script mentioned in that website (under web-browser) it still shows the same error. I am using twitter bootstrap and jquery 2.0.3 hope that's not casing the problem?. I have created a fresh project after installing jquery 2.0.3 IE stop loading.

Comment: can you try to chang the jquery version to <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>, also change the doctype to <!DOCTYPE html> & add <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" /> inside head tag.

Comment: it works. I kept the jquery version same and added <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge;chrome=1" /> on my master page. Thank you